# Is there a common idiom to express the idea: "if you blame your wife once, then you should blame yourself ten times"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

A wife and a husband don't get along well with each other.

One day, the husband puts a pack of pills (that was half-used) on the kitchen counter while cleaning the kitchen. The wife thought the pack was fully used, so she threw it in the garbage.

The husband got upset with his wife for being careless.

The husband's friend said to him "**if you blame your wife once, then you should blame yourself 10 times**" (this is literally translated from Vietnamese, which is my mother tongue).

This implies you must look after your things first rather than relying on others to look after them. Or something like that.

Is there a common expression for conveying this idea?

Comment: Try       https://biblehub.com/matthew/7-3.htm      for a saying of Christ regarding blame. You might find it appropriate.

Comment: @RonaldSole, do you have some simpler sentences. It's too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are many such expressions in English.

I can think of two (off the top of my head).

1. *If you want something done right, do it yourself.*
2. *You have no one to blame but yourself.*

Both of these are often used, although they're not restricted to matrimony.